# Cannot see the content inside the 'Tab' component in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using the `Tabs` component of the`react-bootstrap` framework. When I put an example:

```
<div>
   <p> AAAAAAA </p>
</div>
```

inside `Tab` I don't see anything in this tab.

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="profile" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
  <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
    <div>
      <p>sssssssssssssssssss</p>
    </div>
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="profile" title="Profile">
    <div>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/08/03/12/22/hot-air-balloons-4381674__340.jpg" alt="picture"/>
    </div>
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact" disabled>
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ufa6nq?file=index.js

Comment: Hi Umbro, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the issue is `react-bootstrap` version.

You have `react-bootstrap` `v0.32.4`, which is based on `bootstrap 3`. So removing `bootstrap 4` from your code will fix the issue.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vvvmo1)

---

To work with `bootstrap 4.x` you need to install `react-bootstrap` `v1.0.0-beta.10`.

You can check this [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction), on the header itself.

---

**Note:** By default `stackBlitz` is installing `react-bootstrap` `v0.32.4` (the older version), and not the new version. For this you can raise a query in `stackBlitz` [community](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Can we talk on chat?

Answer (score 2):

You have added three bootstrap css in your project. Two css links are added in `index.html` file and one in `index.js` file.

Remove `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` line from `index.js` file and remove one of the `bootstrap.min.css` link from `index.html` file.

Here I have updated the working code for you.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bootstrap-tabs-3gt7r7

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: If it's work for you then can you please mark an answer as accepted? So it will be helpful for other developer as well.